# SwiftMailer: can't open .tar.gz archives on Linux

Tags: linux, gzip, tar, swiftmailer

I downloaded a couple of versions from
http://swiftmailer.org/downloads/archive
(tar.gz) but the archive manager says

```
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

when I try to open it. Any ideas?

Comment: Strange. Worked for me. I used: `tar xf Swift-5.0.0.tar.gz`.  Exactly which files were you testing?

Comment: Swift-5.0.0.tar.gz and Swift-4.3.1.tar.gz

Comment: Perhaps try: http://fosshelp.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/solution-tar-this-does-not-look-like.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
gzip -d file.tar.gz
```

then:

```
tar -xf file.tar
```

This was taken from:

http://fosshelp.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/solution-tar-this-does-not-look-like.html

Answer (score 0):

Or just `tar xzf file.tar.gz`.  Easier, faster, and takes less disk space.

*Update:*

I don't see why that doesn't work, but ungzipping first does.  In that case, it would be better to:

```
gzip -dc file.tar.gz | tar xzf -
```

which at least uses a pipe to avoid uncompressing and reading back from mass storage.

Comment: I'm still trying this... I mean, I tried it but it has stuck and I had to stop it.

Comment: Oops.  Left off the `f`.  It wasn't stuck without the `f` -- it was just waiting for input from stdin.

Comment: Your suggestion is what I first tryed using `tar` on the terminal, and had the same result then using the archive manager. I guess the only way to skip this problem is to let gzip work on the .gz archive.